# Commands adding spaces

Tags: spacing, macros

I've made a function/command for use mid-sentence, but it adds spaces everywhere it's inserted. Is there a way to flag it so it doesn't make them?

Code:

```
\def \testvar{0}
\newcommand{\test} {
    \ifnum \testvar=1 {
        test0
    }
    \else {
        test1
    }
}
```

Inside document:

```
aaaa \test aaaa
```

Output:

```
aaaa    test1  aaaa
```

Wanted output:

```
aaaa test1 aaaa
```

Comment: Add a `%` to the end of each line in the definition. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines

Comment: you have 7 space tokens in your definition (in addition to the space token that terminates the number `1 ` in the ifnum test)

Comment: Also use it like `aaaa \test{} aaaa` or `aaaa \test\ aaaa` or use `xspace`,

Comment: Adding % seems to work, but there are problems with this "solution":
1. It makes me unable to fold the function - some functions cover the whole screen, I can't work like that
2. It doesn't look like it's the intended way of doing this - I'd prefer to use the TeX components properly

Comment: What do you mean "fold the function"?  Does it have to do with how the definition looks in your editor, or how the output looks in your document?

Comment: I mean clicking the arrow next to a block of code in brackets to hide the contents - most editors have that function. When adding % the arrow disappears on Overleaf.

Comment: I am not familiar with that "function".  However, the only alternative to using `%`  to break a definition into multiple lines without the introduction of space is to not break the definition into multiple lines and keep typing until you hit the `}`.  The treatment of line-ends by TeX is quite well known and documented.  The answer at the linked question does a good job of explaining it.

Comment: Here's an example of what commands I'm dealing with for easier understanding: https://pastebin.com/RWjeCxHV I will have to look into the details of how it works I guess. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to access the site from my office machine.

Comment: I would however, note one aspect of token absorption.  When a line ends on a command, no spurious space is introduced.  So, if you can structure your definition to end lines on, for example, `\else`, `\ifnum`, and `\fi`, no `%` is needed to suppress spurious spaces.

Comment: look at _any_ tex code and you will see that you need to either not add linebreaks or comment them out of you do not want to add space, I do not know why you say that this is not the intended way of marking this up?

Comment: in your pastebin you have lots of `\ifnum #1=0{`  the extra space is coming from the newline after `{` but in that case you do not want the `{` there at all they are just putting groups around your `\paragraph` command, which is not normally wanted, so you could delete the `{` which will also remove the spurious space

Comment: as well as the ends of lines you have `\refstepcounter{zadcounterA}SPACE{`  so additional spaces in the output.

Comment: It's just basic code formatting; looking at code with all white characters removed is an absolute nightmare that I would never subject others to. From what I'm seeing LaTeX isn't too friendly of a language, I'm having a hard time putting up with it, haha.

Comment: @RandomPersson tex markup is optimised for _marking up documents_ and in natural language text white space is not ignorable fluff for pretty printing. I f y o u a d d sp ac e in t h e wron g pla ces it doesn't work.